# UWP SerialDevice : Is my device bad ? Can not connect with Vid,Pid

Tags: uwp, serial-port

UWP app, To connect with Serial device ( like COM3 ), I success to get all available device list with below code. But One point is strange. My Device has no VID, no PID.

[image: USB-RS485 convertor]

1. First, I use "GetDeviceSelector", I can find my Serial Device. and, I got this string "\?\FTDIBUS#VID_0403+PID_6001+AL03INW7A#0000#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}"  then I knew my device has Vid=0x0403, Pid=0x6001.
2. Next If I use "GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(0x0403, 0x6001)". UWP can not find my device...

**Why ??**

First is test code.

```
public MainPage()                                                                                                                  
        {                                                                                                                          
            this.InitializeComponent();                                                                                            

            Task.Run(() => this.test()).Wait();                                                                                    

        }                                                                                                                          

        public async Task test()                                                                                                   
        {                                                                                                                          
            try                                                                                                                    
            {                                                                                                                      
                // Not Work                                                                                                        
                // var DeviceSelector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(0x0403, 0x6001); //                               

                // Work                                                                                                            
                var DeviceSelector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();                                                           
                var DeviceInformations = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceSelector);                                     

                for (int i = 0; i < DeviceInformations.Count; i++)                                                                 
                {                                                                                                                  
                    var d = DeviceInformations[i];                                                                                 
                    SerialDevice port = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(d.Id);                                                      

                    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n---------------------",                           
                        d.Name,                                                                                                    
                        d.Id,                                                                                                      
                        d.IsEnabled,                                                                                               
                        port?.PortName,                                                                                            
                        port?.UsbProductId.ToString("X4"),                                                                             
                        port?.UsbVendorId.ToString("X4")                                                                               
                        ));                                                                                                        


                }                                                                                                                  
            }                                                                                                                      
            catch (Exception ex)                                                                                                   
            {                                                                                                                      
                Debug.WriteLine("SerialController/ListAvailablePorts/Exception/" + ex.Message);                                    
            }                                                                                                                      

            return;                                                                                                                
        }
```

Package.appxmanifest must has this too.

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

and Here is result with GetDeviceSelector.

```
FT232R USB UART
\\?\FTDIBUS#VID_0403+PID_6001+AL03INW7A#0000#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}
True
COM12
0000
0000
```

see last two Zero value. VID, PID look like zero. What is wrong ?

**Update1** :

with Advice of Sunteen Wu (thank you), I tried to use other device. Next device is RS232-USB device. Both device is Virtual COM port. I tried same code. 2nd Device has Vid, Pid !! Hmm..... My device was wrong.....

```
ATEN USB to Serial Bridge (COM13)
\\?\USB#VID_0557&PID_2008#8&1d38065f&1&4#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}
System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ReadOnlyDictionaryValueCollection`2[System.String,System.Object]
COM13
2008
0557
```

[image]

Comment: Could I know what's your device? Did you have another device for testing?

Comment: I bought the device at here .  ( http://www.usconverters.com/usb-to-rs485-converter-iu100 )... I will test another device later....

Comment: I tried another device. Both has Virtual COM ports. 2nd Device has Vid, PId !  ..hmm.... I request this to maker. My First Device is FTDI. Is there anyway to set Vid,Pid by myself ... ?  any way, thank you...

Answer (score 1):

It is my device fault. I reported it to manufacture. I hope They will add Vid, Pid future. **about detail, Please read "update" in my Question.**

Before purchase, There is no way to know it... : (

I like their product. It's very good.